# run time error 1004 when trying to select a rectangle range of values

Tags: vba, excel

I wonder if anyone knows how to select a rectangle range of values? This range will not be fixed. For this particular example, it will select B5 - G7 in a rectangle form and then it will set a condition format to add in some colors.

I have attempted the codebut it is giving me an error at this portion

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(colorrow & "2", _
ActiveSheet.Cells(colorrow & "2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
```

wonder if anyone know why? will be thankful!

[image]

I have attempted writing out some coding.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub Macro2()

 Dim thevaluestocopy As Variant, colorCell as Range, colorrow as Long, thefirstcolorrow as Long

 colorrow = 1

Do

Set colorCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(colorrow, 1)
'check for test1-test6 if its around do nothing, else goes to the next row and next column
If colorCell = "test1" Or colorCell = "test2" Or colorCell = "test3" _
Or colorCell = "test4" Or colorCell = "test5" Or colorCell = "test6" _ Then 
'Do nothing
Else
thefirstcolorrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(colorrow, 2)
'This statement gives me the error.. not sure why it cant work 
ActiveSheet.Cells(colorrow & "2", _
ActiveSheet.Cells(colorrow & "2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
Exit Do
End If
colorrow = colorrow + 1
Loop


'add colors into cell
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
    xlConditionValueLowestValue
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
    .Color = 8109667
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
    xlConditionValuePercentile
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
    .Color = 8711167
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
    xlConditionValueHighestValue
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
    .Color = 7039480
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I think there is a better way to do it. Can you confirm that the data will always be in that order. i.e a "test1" will never appear after a "droptest" or a "hardtest" or "softtest"?

Comment: yup.. it will not happen after those 3 tests... but i think mine should be ok.. I have tried out a number of examples, it actually work fine...

Comment: Ok then we will leave it at that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out a way. and like to share it with the rest..

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim colorCell As Range, colorrow As Long, thefirstcolorrow As Long, colorrow1 As Long, colorCell1 As Range, nvalue As Long
Dim thelastcolorRow As Long, n As Long, LastColtocolor As Long

colorrow = 1

LastColtocolor = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells("1" & Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Do

Set colorCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(colorrow, 1)

'Check if cell holds any value of test1 - test6, etc...
If colorCell = "test1" Or colorCell = "test2" Or colorCell = "test3" _
Or colorCell = "test4" Or colorCell = "test5" Or colorCell = "test6" _ Then 
'Do nothing
 Else
 thefirstcolorrow = colorrow

Exit Do
End If

colorrow = colorrow + 1
Loop

colorrow1 = 1

Do
'Look for last row that has values
Set colorCell1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(colorrow1, 1)
If colorCell1 = "" Then
thelastcolorRow = colorrow1

Exit Do
End If
colorrow1 = colorrow1 + 1
Loop

For nvalue = 1 To colorrow1 - 1 - colorrow

Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(thefirstcolorrow, 2), Cells(thefirstcolorrow + nvalue, LastColtocolor)).Select

Next nvalue

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you mean, but if you'd like to reference a rectangular range in a worksheet you can use the following:

```
With Sheet1
  .Range(.Range("B5"), .Range("G7")).Select
End With
```

That'll select B5:G7 in the object called Sheet1. Alternatively you could use the sheet name:

```
With Sheets("Sheet 1")
  .Range(.Range("B5"), .Range("G7")).Select
End With
```

Note that Sheet1.Name is most likely equal to "Sheet 1", i.e. Sheet1 is the object, "Sheet 1" is the name of the object. If you understand (or learn to understand) this distinction you'll probably be doing yourself a great service.

Edit:
Change

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(colorrow & "2", _ ActiveSheet.Cells(colorrow & "2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(colorrow & "2"), ActiveSheet.Cells(colorrow & "2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
```

Comment: hi, i have tried the one u asked me to change, it did not select what i expect and it also changes the value of my first row first column

Comment: hi, i have changed my code a little because of the changed value that i mentioned earlier.. but still the code you given selects the range that i dont expect it to select